# Redirect Traffic to new webfolder. URI Redirection on Linux

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

There are a bunch of website files in the main web root directory /var/www.
Now  I want to be able to move all these into a sub folder to clean up the www folder.

The Problem

When I moved all the files into the subfolder the website looses track of its css, png, jpg and many other files and links on the website.

Currently Sites Avaiable in the apache2 looks like this

```
 <---/etc/apache2/sites-available---->
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule !/.(js|htm;|ico|pdf|css|doc|xls|xml)$ /index.php
```

I moved all the sites contents into a folder. The structure now looks like

```
 /var/www/LiveSite
```

When debugging in the webbrowser for example a warning appears

Cannot Locate `http://192.168.1.5/Resources/imgs/file.png`

Though now the images resides in `http:/192.168.1.5/LiveSite/Resources/imgs/file.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `/var/www/.htaccess` file with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(Resources/.+)$ /LiveSite/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: How come I dont need  to escape the / in (Resources/.+)$?
Shouldnt it be (Resources\/.+)

Comment: No `/` doesn't need to be escaped at all in `mod_rewrite`